# GPG unable to delete secret key

Tags: gnupg

I was trying to delete the GPG private and public keys that were generated in my server. I got an error saying "gpg: deleting secret key failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device". A quick google search and i typed "export GPG_TTY=$(tty)" to fix the ioctl error.

Now when I try to delete the secret keys again, it errors out with "gpg: deleting secret key failed: No such file or directory". Have you guys encountered this before?

```
root@blahblah:/# gpg --delete-secret-keys 840AF4E6
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27; Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


sec  rsa2048/34D79E35840AF4E6 2022-02-23 Autogenerated Key <email@company.com>

Delete this key from the keyring? (y/N) Y
This is a secret key! - really delete? (y/N) Y
gpg: deleting secret key failed: No such file or directory
gpg: 840AF4E6: delete key failed: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I used python's gnupg module to create these keys. After reading the docs, I found a way to delete the secret keys.

```
print(str(gpg.delete_keys('ED353CD1B038A91F103B005534D79E35840AF4E6', True, passphrase = "mypassphrase")))
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your zprofile or bashprofile:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

Restart the terminal and try to delete it again.